# setting PATH env variable not working

Tags: 12.04, paths

I want to set Sonar-Runner bin directory in PATH in `.profile` directory in Ubuntu.

When I execute `echo $PATH` it is showing the path that I set, but when I try to run sonar-runner.bat file using

```
./sonar-runner -h`
```

the results i get are

```
bash: ./sonar-runner: No such file or directory
```

But if I run the same command

```
./sonar-runner -h
```

from its directory, it runs just fine. I know its *env var* problem. But I am not able to resolve it.

Please can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./` is an absolute path and points to the current working directory.

By providing an absolute path the shell won't search PATH.

So just type: `sonar-runner -h` and it should work.